# POST json to rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, http, post

```
def create
  req = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body)
  if user = User.authenticate(req["email"], req["password"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    render :json => "{\"r\": \"t\"}" + req
  else
    render :json => "{\"r\": \"f\"}"
  end
end
```

'create' method is in a controller and mapped to "/login", I am setting correct content types and accept headers from my curl client. I am getting a 422 http status response all the time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: no need to build the JSON response by hand: render :json => {:r => "f"}.as_json

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you are sending in the right headers, then you won't need to do "ActiveSupport::JSON.decode" -- rails will do that for you.

You'll need to set the following headers in your post.

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

A 422 means Unprocessable Entity --- generally that there was a validation failure.

You should be able to have. If you can't, then your headers aren't set correctly.

```
def create
  if user = User.authenticate(params["email"], params["password"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    render :json => "{\"r\": \"t\"}" + req
  else
    render :json => "{\"r\": \"f\"}"
  end
end
```

Comment: so all my json POST request body is put into the params[] hash automatically? So can i use more deep object structures in json and will they be parsed correctly?

Comment: Yes. Deeper structures will require that you set the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your models. (parent accepts for child)

Comment: BTW, a if you send the request headers to the server, make sure you use : and not =, as in:   "Content-Type: application/json" and
"Accepts: application/json"

Comment: @Ran its Accept not Accepts!