# How could I send JSON object and get in return js code in rails 3.1?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a list of html input items in my html page each representing different model. On click of the submit button, I would like to send all the details as a json object to the controller. From the controller, I would like to return the js code to the browser.

As far as the examples I have seen, they are either sending the data as json and receive json from the server else send the data using form_for and receive the js code from the server. But I would like to send json and receive back js code. How i can do this in rails 3.1 using jQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914745/post-json-to-rails-server describes a way to send and parse json, to respond with JS just render proper partial

Comment: @Bohdan Pohorilets: awesome find. never actually realized that setting a proper header should also be considered instead of taking the overhead of decoding the response into json in the controller side. nice !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this Railscast by Ryan Bates provides detailed instructions for doing exactly what you are describing.

[Railscast Episode #136 - JQuery](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery)

That was the railscast I used when I was first learning to post data using jquery in a JSON format and return javascript. It was really helpful.

Though the Rails version is not 3.1, you should be able to adapt the ideas quickly.