# Rails 3 params unwanted wrapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm posting some JSON like the JSON form of `{:name => "hello"}` to my Rails 3 controller ExampleController.

Instead of getting `params` like:

```
{:name => "hello"}
```

I'm getting:

```
{:name => "hello", :controller => "example", :action => "index", :example => {:name => "hello"}
```

(Yes the JSON data appears twice! and action and controller are added)

Any idea why ?

Comment: Are you setting the content-accept and Accepts headers as I wrote here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914745/post-json-to-rails-server

Comment: Yes -- it's posted from jQuery $.ajax with type: json

Answer (score 37, accepted):

ActionController automatically does this for JSON requests so that you can easily pass the parameters into `Example.create` or `@example.update_attributes`, which means the client doesn't need to package them up for your model -- it can just include `name` et. al. at the top level of your JSON data and the controller will handle the grouping.

```
@example = Example.create params[:example]
```

The parameter wrapping code gets the name of your model from the name of the controller, but you can change it using the [wrap_parameters](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) macro in your controller:

```
wrap_parameters :thing
```

Or turn it off with

```
wrap_parameters false
```

In Rails 3.2, if your model uses `attr_accessible`, the parameter wrapping feature will also exclude any parameters that are not accessible to mass assignment. You can also use the macro to make this wrapping feature apply to other content types besides JSON, if you like.

By default in a newly created Rails app, this is configured for all controllers using an initializer. Look for `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`.