# Is rails creating a new params[:model] hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I wanted to check if the behaviour I'm seeing is indeed what I think it is.

I've googled for the answer, but can't find any documentation that confirms that this is expected behaviour.

I'm using Backbone 0.9.2.1 and Rails 3.2.3

When I save my model in backbone, I'm looking at the HTTP headers and seeing that it sends a JSON representation, eg

```
{"title":"I think...","id":2,...}
```

Inside the controller, I've been absent mindedly using params[:opinion] which oddly was working fine, but now I've hit a hitch, and I'm noticing that my params hash is actually

```
{"title" => "I think...",
"id" => 2
"opinion" => {"title" => "I think ..."},
...
```

(The reason I've hit the hitch is the id is present in params[:id] but not params[:opinion][:id]

It appears to me that any params that match the name of a attr_accessible are mapped into this params[:opinion] hash before the controller method is invoked.

The model is, of course, Opinion.
The controller is called opinion_controller and is being reached by this route:

```
  resources :stories, :controller => 'opinions'
```

(in the process of renaming some things)

Is this expected behaviour?
Could someone point me to the documentation where I can read up on this?

Comment: Are you using [wrap_parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper/ClassMethods.html#method-i-wrap_parameters) in your application?

Comment: Ah, I see this is in my config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
I didn't deliberately set it, but I guess a default rails app includes that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup I ran into this same thing and was wondering wtf. Rails auto wraps it as you saw. The change:
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/359

**Edit:** 
From the API doc:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

`By default, if you don’t specify the key in which the parameters would be wrapped to, ParamsWrapper will actually try to determine if there’s a model related to it or not.`

This answer also describes it well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134057/341692

Comment: Thanks, is it documented anywhere else except in the github?

Comment: Actually just found the api doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html  "By default, if you don’t specify the key in which the parameters would be wrapped to, ParamsWrapper will actually try to determine if there’s a model related to it or not."