# How can can.js add a record to a Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, canjs

I am using Can.js to add a record to a Ruby on Rails server:

```
var Todo = can.Model({
  findAll : 'GET /todos',
  findOne : 'GET /todos/{id}',
  create  : 'POST /todos',
  update  : 'PUT /todos/{id}',
  destroy : 'DELETE /todos/{id}'
}, {});

Todo.prototype.description = function() {
    return this.name + " and " + this.complete;
};

Todo.findAll({}, function(todos) {
    todos.each(function(todo) {
        console.log(todo.name, todo.complete);
        console.log(todo.description());
    });
});

var todo = new Todo({name: "mow lawn"});

todo.save();
```

the `findAll()` actually can get all the records, but the `save()` will insert a blank record.  I suspected it might be the `CSRF token`, but that shows as a warning, and if it didn't want to insert the record, it probably won't create any record at all, instead of adding a record with name being nothing?  (I also tried `var todo = new Todo({name: "mow lawn", complete: true});` and it is the same result).

but the Rails server prints out on the terminal as:

```
Started POST "/todos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-12 08:16:05 -0700
Processing by TodosController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"mow lawn"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "todos" ("complete", "created_at", "name", "updated_at") 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["complete", nil], ["created_at", Fri, 12 Apr 2013 15:16:05 UTC 
+00:00], ["name", nil], ["updated_at", Fri, 12 Apr 2013 15:16:05 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.5ms)  commit transaction
Completed 201 Created in 11ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
```

In the Chrome developer tool, I see in Network:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/todos
Request Method:POST

part of header:
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

form data:
name:mow lawn
```

If my action is:

```
  def create
    p "params[:todo] is", params[:todo]
    @todo = Todo.new(params[:todo])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo, notice: 'Todo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @todo, status: :created, location: @todo }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

then terminal will show:

```
"params[:todo] is"
nil
```

even though the terminal shows the standard Rails log:

```
Parameters: {"name"=>"mow lawn"}
```

Comment: What does your Rails controller action code look like?

Comment: it is just a standard scaffold... but I added the code above

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the Rails console output, your `params` Hash looks like the following:

```
Parameters: {"name"=>"mow lawn"}
```

But your controller is creating a new Todo instance using the following:

```
@todo = Todo.new(params[:todo])
```

`:todo` is not in the `params` Hash, so `params[:todo]` is `nil` and basically your Todo instance has no attributes passed to it, hence it is saving `nil` for the `name` column in the DB.

Your controller should be using [parameter wrapping](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) to solve this, which will wrap all the `params` Hash into a `params[:todo]` sub-Hash. So if you have this in your controller:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  wrap_parameters :todo
  ...
end
```

Your `params` Hash will be transformed to the following before the action is performed:

```
Parameters: {"name"=>"mow lawn", "todo" => {"name"=>"mow lawn"}}
```

And then your existing action code should work.

Comment: yes I just saw that too... so the question is, is Can.js doing it correctly or Rails doing it correctly?  One thing though, is, if we are posting to /todos, why would we again post a complete object like `todo: {name: ..., complete: ...}` vs just `name: ..., complete: ...` ?

Comment: Does `Parameters:` change in your Rails console output?

Comment: For explanation why parameter wrapping can be helpful see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133652/rails-3-params-unwanted-wrapping

Comment: And I believe Can.js is sending the POST correctly, it just needs to be interpreted correctly on the receiving (server) side. You could also potentially use `Todo.new(params)` but you run the risk of including extra meta-parameters from the request, such as `_method` or others that don't belong on the model

Comment: I have tried `wrap_parameters`, `wrap_parameters :todo`, `wrap_parameters :todos`, `wrap_parameters :todo, :include => [:name, :complete]`, `wrap_parameters :include => [:name, :complete]` and restarted the server and the records are still empty and it prints
 `Parameters: {"name"=>"mow lawn 76391", "complete"=>"true"}`.  The only way I can get it to work is `@todo = Todo.new(:name => params[:name], :complete => params[:complete])` but would still be interested in how `wrap_parameters` can be used

Comment: Do you have this initializer file in your project: `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb` ? See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html#config-initializers-wrap_parameters-rb

Comment: I just had this exact problem, rails `wrap_parameters` wants `application/json` but canjs sends `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`... canjs do this is to get around cross-domain issues.. but you can do that anyway is you have access to the server. I'll add an answer with the code that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Like **Stuart M** said, you need to set the `wrap_parameters :todo` in the controller.

But `wrap_parameters :todo` does not work with the default `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` canjs sends on it's model updates.

Here are the resources that let me work it out:

https://github.com/bitovi/canjs/issues/111

https://forum.javascriptmvc.com/topic/howto-use-application-json-and-encode-data-automatically-in-can-model

So by reading those I changed my app to look like this:

**app/controllers/todo_controller.rb**

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  wrap_parameters :todo

  def create
    Todo.new(params[:todo])
  end

end
```

**app/assets/javascripts/canjs.models.js**

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR){
    if( options.processData && /^(post|put|patch|delete)$/i.test( options.type ))
    {
        options["contentType"] = "application/json";
        options["data"] = JSON.stringify(originalOptions["data"]);
    }
});

Todo = Model.new({
    ...
});
```

And everything worked like magic :)

---

**NOTE:** You may need to setup CORS for this to work, here is how to set it up on a public api:

**config/routes.rb**

```
SomeTodoApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :todos, except: [:new, :edit]

  match "*all" => "application#cors_preflight_check", via: :options

end
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API

# protect_from_forgery is always a good thing if you know your clients can support get it working

  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :cors_preflight_check
  after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

# For all responses in this controller, return the CORS access control headers.

  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, PATCH, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
  end

# If this is a preflight OPTIONS request, then short-circuit the
# request, return only the necessary headers and return an empty
# text/plain.

  def cors_preflight_check
    if request.method == :options
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, PATCH, GET, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
      headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
      render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
    end
  end

end
```