# In Rails, how to convert form data automatically into a param ready to create an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Can.js to create a new record, and it sends a `POST /todos` to the local Rails server (rails 3.2.13).
The form data in the request is `title=mow+lawn&completed=true` which is:

```
title: mow lawn
completed: true
```

so in the `TodosController`, the `create` action, the default code is:

```
@todo = Todo.new(params[:todo])
```

but of course, the `params[:todo]` is empty, and only `params[:title]` and `params[:completed]` exist.  So I can use

```
@todo = Todo.new(:title => params[:title], :completed => params[:completed])
```

to do it, but is there a way to make it somehow automatically create such a `param` or an object from those params?

Someone suggested in [How can can.js add a record to a Rails server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975309/how-can-can-js-add-a-record-to-a-rails-server)

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  wrap_parameters :todo
```

but I tried each of

```
wrap_parameters
wrap_parameters :todo
wrap_parameters :todo, :include => [:name, :complete], 
wrap_parameters :include => [:name, :complete]
```

and still `Todo.new(params[:todo])` won't work.  How does it actually work or any other method to pack the params into an object automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@todo = Todo.new(params.slice(:name, :completed))
```

To make it automatic, I guess you could slice the `accessible_attributes` method for the model:

```
@todo = Todo.new(params.slice(*Todo.accessible_attributes))
```

Comment: so that's like taking those two params out from the whole hash... is there something that's automatic that we can list under `class TodosController < ApplicationController`, and that if `todo` now has a new field that's `priority`, then we don't have to go through the code every where and add `:priority` to `params.slice(:name, :completed)`?  (that is, Rails will do it for us)