# $http service adding unwanted JSON key to request data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple service which I'm using to POST data to a Rails controller.

My service looks something like this:

```
app.service('autoRulesService', function($http) {
  return({
    createRule: createRule
  });

  function createRule() {
    var request = $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/rules.json',
      data: { one: 'two }
    });

    return request.then(handleSuccess, handleError);
  }

  function handleSuccess() {
    // body omitted...
  }
  function handleError() {
    // body omitted...
  }
});
```

I use that service in my controller in a pretty standard way:

```
$scope.saveRule = function() {
  rulesService.createRule().then(function() {
    // do stuff...
  });
}
```

The problem is that I get a weird unwanted key in my parameters when I inspect the sent data in the Rails log. Where is the `"rule"` parameter coming from?

```
Processing by AutoAnalysis::RulesController#create as JSON
   Parameters: {"one"=>"two", "rule"=>{}}
```

It doesn't appear in the request payload (as inspected in Chrome Dev tools)

[image: request payload]

and my controller action is pretty standard (there's no before filters either):

```
class RulesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # NOTE: I'm referencing an :auto_analysis_rule parameter here because 
    # that's my desired param key name. It doesn't exist in the request
    # as shown here.
    render json: Rule.create(params[:auto_analysis_rule])
  end
end
```

and I can't find any mention of `$http` inferring a root JSON key from the URL or anything [in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Where is the `"rule"` param key coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails automatically wraps parameters that are attributes of the model. If `one` were an attribute of the Rule model, the payload would look like: `{"rule" => {"one" => "two"}}`

This functionality removes the need for a top-level key that contains all attributes. In other words, the following payloads would be treated the same if `attr1` and `attr2` are fields in the `MyModel` model:

```
{ "mymodel" : { "attr1" : "val1", "attr2" : "val2" } }

{ "attr1" : "val1", "attr2" : "val2" }
```

This functionality can be disabled per-controller or app-wide in an initializer. Check out this answer for more information: [Rails 3 params unwanted wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133652/rails-3-params-unwanted-wrapping)

Comment: Wow. I've somehow being working with Rails for about 4 years without this occurring to me. I guess I've just never tried to mess with the root key of the JSON object I'm sending up so it always just worked transparently. Thanks.