# Retrofit 2 sending duplicated parameters

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using retrofit in my app to send a POST request, but the parameters are being sent twice and I can't find the reason.

This is my api:

```
public interface ChoferesApi {
    @POST("myurl/")
    Call<Chofer> registroChofer(@Body Chofer chofer);
}
```

My POJO object:

```
public class Chofer {
  private String apellido;
  private String nombre;
  private String email;
  private int dni;
  private String sexo;
  private Date fechaNacimiento;
  private String password;

  //Getters & Setters...
```

}

The request:

```
Call<Chofer> call = RestClient.getInstance().registroChofer(chofer);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Chofer>() { ... });
```

In logcat I only see the parameters once (according to okhttp):

```
    11-09 18:46:53.170 27197-27742/com.mypackage D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.1.5:3000/myurl http/1.1
    11-09 18:46:53.170 27197-27742/com.mypackage D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    11-09 18:46:53.170 27197-27742/com.mypackage D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 139
    11-09 18:46:53.170 27197-27742/com.mypackage D/OkHttp: {"apellido":"aaa","sexo":"masculino","email":"a@a.com","fecha_nacimiento":"2016-10-09","nombre":"aaa","password":"effdggffy","dni":1234564}
    11-09 18:46:53.170 27197-27742/com.mypackage D/OkHttp: --> END POST (139-byte body)
```

But in my server, the following parameters are received:

```
Started POST "/myurl" for 192.168.1.13 at 2016-11-09 16:39:05 -0300
Cannot render console from 192.168.1.13! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by MyController#myaction as HTML
Parameters: {"apellido"=>"gh", "sexo"=>"masculino", "email"=>"a@a.com", "fecha_nacimiento"=>"2016-10-09", "nombre"=>"ggg", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "dni"=>54577457, "registro"=>{"apellido"=>"gh", "sexo"=>"masculino", "email"=>"a@a.com", "fecha_nacimiento"=>"2016-10-09", "nombre"=>"ggg", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "dni"=>54577457}}
```

As can be seen, the parameters are being sent twice, the second time inside an object called "registro" and I can't figure out why. I tried sending the same request using POSTMAN and the parameters are only sent once, so this is NOT a server-side issue.

Answer (score 1):

You send it as *@Body* (and Your POJO is probably parsing  to JSON) not *@Query* parameters, so maybe that is an issue ?

Comment: Yes, my POJO class is being parsed to JSON. I'm using Body annotation because I want to send the data as POST paramaters. If I used the Query annotation, data would be sent as Query parameters in the url which is not the idea.

Comment: @VorteXavier Ok, I understand. And when you send it by Postman, you send it as JSON too or as form parameters?

Comment: Yes I'm seeing them as form parameters. I will try to send it as Json tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, have you tried use _@Field_ annotation ? One example is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517182/android-java-post-with-headers-with-retrofit-2-1-0/40518034#40518034)

Comment: I didn't try to use _@Field_, but I'm quite sure it will work with it. The thing is that I don't want to lose the simplicity that the  _@Body_ annotation gives (With the serialization stuff). I will end up using _@Field_ as a last resort if I can't find what is causing this.

Comment: I tried sending and Json and I figured out what the error is, I will post the answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. In the end it was a server-side issue not related to retrofit. In the server I'm using Ruby on Rails 4, and in the POST request that I'm sending the parameters are wraped as Json (This is what retrofit does when using the *@Body* annotation).

The problem was that Rails controllers automatically wraps all the parameters sent around an object with the same name as the controller (in my case: 'registro'). This only happens when the parameters are sent as Json, thats why the request I sent through POSTman didn't have this problem.

Here is a Stackoverflow post giving further explanation on the subject:
[Rails 3 params unwanted wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133652/rails-3-params-unwanted-wrapping)

Conclusion: The problem was not related to retrofit nor okhttp; it was a specific behaviour in my server.