# How to save values of a JSON response in a rails database?

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, json, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to access the Facebook Graph API and get JSON responses like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Coldplay", 
      "category": "Musician/band", 
      "id": "15253175252", 
      "created_time": "2012-01-27T22:51:44+0000"
    },
    {
      "name": "R.E.M.", 
      "category": "Musician/band", 
      "id": "8759772983", 
      "created_time": "2012-01-27T22:51:43+0000"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/1000032123447/music?format=json&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=8123918"
  }
}
```

Now I want to save the name, the category and id into my rails database.
I have got a table with the same columns.

What is the easiest way to save this response into the matching columns of the database? Or is there a better solution, i.e. just saving the whole json object into the database and read it later on in the code again?

If you have time, please provide a coding example for the javascript/jQuery (ajax maybe) and ruby code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914745/post-json-to-rails-server) for how to send JSON content from the browser to a Rails app.

Then you can do something like this (the JSON will be parsed automatically, and available as the `params` hash). One thing to note, is that the `id` attribute in the JSON will be ignored, since it's protected by default (Rails uses `id` as the primary key for records). Better to "rename it" to something like `facebook_id`:

```
# POST /path/to/collection
def create
  params["data"].each do |data|
    data["facebook_id"] = data["id"]
    SomeRecordClass.create(data)
  end
end
```

Of course you'll want to do some error checking, send a response, etc.

In the browser, you can do something like this, if you're using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/path/to/collection",
  data: data, // the JSON data, as an object or string
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: thanks! Could you also add the javascript to call this method, i.e. in Ajax?

Comment: @SebastianOberste-Vorth Added the bare minimum JS. The rest is up to you, though, since I'm not inclined to do all your work for you